# Alternative Bibliography Processor with context MKIV

Tags: bibliographies, context, context-mkiv

Do MLBibTeX work with ConTeXt MKIV? If yes, the how to use it with mkiv?

Comment: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00644461/document, https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-1/tb86hufflen.pdf, https://www.ntg.nl/maps/45/13.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I really recommend *not* to use MLBibTeX with ConTeXt MkIV, because it has an internal bibliography processor.  You can read about it in the following references:

- [From BibTeX to ConTeXt MkIV](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2014/talks/2014-09-09-alan-bibtex/From_BibTeX_to_ConTeXt_MKVI.pdf): Slides by Alan Braslau from the ConTeXt meeting in 2014
- [Bibliographies the ConTeXt way](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf): this is the manual

Below you find a simple example of how to use it.

```
\startbuffer[biblio]
@book{Knuth1984,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The \TeX book},
  year         = 1984,
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[biblio.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\starttext
\cite[Knuth1984]
\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```