# What is MlBibTeX? Why are there almost no question about it?

Tags: bibliographies, packages

I was reading the program of the [GuIT meeting 2016](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/meeting) and I've seen that one of the talks will be about MlBibTeX.

As far as I've understood it is an evolution of BibTeX processor, with multilingual features, but I've found only [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323578/alternative-bibliography-processor-with-context-mkiv/323666#323666) about it here on TEX.SE.

Why is it so slightly mentioned here?
Is it still in testing phase?
Is it outdated by biber with BibLaTeX?

Comment: I'm assuming it's such a niche product, that if you use it, you know how to answer most of questions arising

Comment: Try finding any usable code!

Comment: Lack of public releases?

Comment: I heard a talk about it two years ago at the dante meating. There were some interesting ideas in it but my personal conclusion was that biber is more powerfull and that these ideas should be better implemented in biblatex (but naturally my view is biased as I made a talk about biblatex at the same meeting ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree with you, I was wondering why to enhance bibtex if there is biber/BibLaTeX now (I apologize to authors of MlBibTeX).

Comment: Oh God. "meating". I shouldn't write comments when my head is in the kitchen pondering about what to make for lunch.

Comment: MlBibTeX is the work of jean-michel hufflen; there have been several articles about it in tugboat through the period 2003-2011, but nothing more recent.  (to access the articles, go to http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listauthor.html and search for "Hufflen".)

Comment: Thank you, @barbarabeeton! It's still more strange: if there is nothing recent what are they going to show at the meeting? I'm puzzled...

Comment: @CarLaTeX -- i can't say for certainty what has or hasn't been happening with respect to MlBibTeX, but since jean-michel is listed as the speaker at the guit meeting, my guess is that he is still working on it, and has something new to share.

Comment: @barbarabeeton unfortunately I cannot attend the meeting, I'd have been curious to listen to him!

Comment: `MlBibTeX`is really a strange case. Although Jean-Michel Hufflen regularly presents paper about it, it seems to remain vapoware. AFAICS, there has never been any kind of public release. Even Hufflen's website which he gives in the latest article in TugBoat 38/2 does not seem to exist.

Comment: @Simifilm Thank you for adding your infos! :):):)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up the comments above: MlBibTeX is still in a testing phase, and at the moment there is no usable code nor any documentation.

*But there is some news*: the author himself, at GuIT Meeting 2017, said that the package will be available on CTAN in December, for the curious ones who would like to try it, maybe this will be the one!

Comment: December has come and and gone, and again, nothing has happened. Call me unsurprised.

Comment: @Simifilm LOL, I think it's a neverending story...