# Multiple bibliography references lists in different languages

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing

What would be the best way to implement the same bibliography list in two languages. Also, consider sorting. For instance:

John Doe et al.[1] invented B. A [2] is interesting. For sure [3].

Список литературы:

[1] Статья B.

[2] Статья A.

[3] Статья C.

References:

[1] Paper B.

[2] Paper A.

[3] Paper C.

Comment: With `biblatex` you could do `\selectlanguage{british}
\printbibliography
\selectlanguage{russian}
\printbibliography` if both `british` and `russian` are loaded with `babel`, but I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This strongly depends on what you actually have in mind. With `biblatex` is is very easy to switch the language and print the same bibliography again, but the data will stay the same, only the translated strings and other localisation features change.

```
\documentclass[french,russian,british]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography[title={\refname\ in document language}]
\selectlanguage{russian}
\printbibliography[title={\refname\ in Russian}]
\selectlanguage{french}
\printbibliography[title={\refname\ in French}]
\end{document}
```

[image: The same bibliography in three different languages: The data is the same in each, only the localisation strings and some details change slightly.]

A while ago there was talk about a multi-script version of `biblatex` that could also change the displayed *data* with the surrounding language, but unfortunately that part of the `biblatex` project is currently dormant. (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/ms and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416) I'd love if that would be picked up again some time, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the records, MlBibTeX was specially designed by Jean-Marie Hufflen for this purpose. It is written in Scheme (a Lisp dialect) and introduces several macros to select outputs depending on the language. It supports unicode since its version 1.4, and computes bib files under LaTeX and ConTeXt.

The trouble is it is documented the traditionnal way, nor avalaible on CTAN. If you want to use it, you have to fetch the source (which is not so easy) and compile them using a Scheme interpreter, Bigloo being the preferred one. If you can compile it, it will work. I dont't know of any other user than it's author yet.

There is of course a [TeX S.E. post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334969/what-is-mlbibtex-why-are-there-almost-no-question-about-it) explaining these issues.

Jean-Marie Hufflen reguralry gives speeches and articles introducing his program. It's been a decade since almost each GUST (Polish Users Group) journal has an article introducing one or more functions. Most are available on-line. Here is a sample,

- [names in BibTeX and MlBibTeX](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87hufflen.pdf)
- [bibliography styles](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00644459/file/hufflen06b_oip.pdf)
- [overall presentation](https://manualzz.com/doc/7180890/mlbibtex--a-new-implementation-of-bibtex)